# Spring Data - дублирование записей в соседнюю таблицу

Tags: spring-data

Периодически встает вопрос архивирования записей для сохранения истории. Самый простой (и вполне удовлетворяющий) способ - это писать сразу в две таблицы / индекса / иную единицу хранилища и при удалении записи удалять только из основного хранилища, однако он требует написания однообразного boilerplate-кода. Есть ли уже существующие решения?

Answer (score 1):

В spring-data такие возможности из коробки не предусмотрены. Можно в базе создать триггеры на `insert/update` или `delete`. Но если всё же хочется чистого спринга (за исключением наличия второй таблицы в базе), то добро пожаловать дальше.

---

Сразу оговорюсь, что реализацию через поддержку @PrePersist и т.п. рассматривать не буду (мы же хотим сделать это прозрачно для объекта).

Итак приступим. Хитрость не в самом spring-data, а в использовании [прокси](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class[],%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29). Создание прокси - дело отдельной темы. Надо создать свою spring-фабрику объектов-репозиториев, унаследованную от [стандартной](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactory.html) и перед конечной отдачей объекта-менеджера (репозитория) завернуть его в прокси. Дальше дело за малым. Если метод начинается с префикса `delete`, то перед его передачей внутрь "реального" объекта-менеджера стоит запустить `insert into ${table}_history select from ${table} where bla-bla....`.

Вытаскивание реального содержимого `where bla-bla....` тема отдельной истории, поэтому здесь это рассматривать не буду. Собственно сама концепция изложена.

Comment: Да, хочется сделать все максимально независимо от базы, чтобы потом прыгнуть на другой движок. Писать свой вытаскиватель потому и боюсь, что придется очень много чего делать, и вероятность выстрелить в ногу довольно велика.

Comment: Если у тебя везде есть Id-поле, который обозначено аннотацией, то это довольно таки просто. Нужно всего-то исследовать класс и достать это поле.